# How can I solve multivariable linear equation in python?

Tags: python, linear-algebra

I have 10,000 variables. for 100 of them, I do know the exact value.

others are given like:

```
a = 0.x_1 * b + 0.y_2 * c+ 0.z_1 * d + (1 - 0.x_1 - 0.y_1 - 0.z_1) * a
b = 0.x_2 * c + 0.y_2 * d+ 0.z_2 * e + (1 - 0.x_2 - 0.y_2 - 0.z_2) * b

...

q = 0.x_10000 * p + 0.y_10000 * r+ 0.z_10000 * s + (1 - 0.x_10000 - 0.y_10000 - 0.z_10000) * q
```

yes I know exact value of 0.x_n, 0.y_n, 0.z_n ... (the point of having 0. as a prefix means it is less than 1 while bigger than 0)

How can I solve this in python? I'd really appreciate if you can provide me some example, with simple equations like this :

```
x - y + 2z =  5
    y -  z = -1
         z =  3
```

Comment: have a look at http://maxima.sourceforge.net/, http://code.google.com/p/sympy/

Comment: Have you googled for answers, thkang? What did you find?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(Using [numpy](https://numpy.org/)) If we rewrite the system of linear equations

```
x - y + 2z =  5
    y -  z = -1
         z =  3
```

as the matrix equation

```
A x = b
```

with

```
A = np.array([[ 1, -1,  2],
              [ 0,  1, -1],
              [ 0,  0,  1]])
```

and

```
b = np.array([5, -1, 3])
```

then `x` can be found using `np.linalg.solve`:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([(1, -1, 2), (0, 1, -1), (0, 0, 1)])
b = np.array([5, -1, 3])
x = np.linalg.solve(A, b)
```

yields

```
print(x)
# [ 1.  2.  3.]
```

We can check that `A x = b`:

```
print(np.dot(A,x))
# [ 5. -1.  3.]

assert np.allclose(np.dot(A,x), b)
```

Comment: Could you please explain why you change A to a 1d array later in the code?

Comment: `A = np.array([(1, -1, 2), (0, 1, -1), (0, 0, 1)])` is a 2D array, just written on one line.