# How to find polynomial for the given roots with sympy/python

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

Assume I have a third-degree polynomial with roots at -2, 1, and 3, how do I find its equation? Is this solvable with `sympy` or maybe there are other ways with python in general?

The function may like and I want to solve `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`.

```py
f = lambda x: a*x**3+b*x**2+c*x+d
```

Meanwhile, what if the polynomial is fifth-degree?

**Update:**

Thanks for the answers. It seems like using Vieta's formula simplified the question. But sometimes the number of roots for an N-th degree polynomial does not equal to N. For example, a fifth-degree polynomial may be expressed as the following:

```
(x-a)**2*(x-b)**2(x-c)
```

If so, is this still solvable?

*Please see my solution below for this Update*

Comment: I'd just take the math approach and use vieta's formulas. If a N degree polynomial has roots a, b, c, d..., then the polynomial can be represented as C(x - a)(x-b)(x-c)(x-d) ..., with C being an unknown constant. C is there because you can multiply a polynomial by whatever and the roots will remain the same, so you don't know what it's been multiplied by.

Comment: @Primusa thanks, I will try and I'm looking at this [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523026/how-can-i-solve-multivariable-linear-equation-in-python) now

Comment: @Primusa Sorry I don't quite understand. I read your solution but a list of 7 roots indeed returned the 7th-degree polynomial. For example, if I have a list of root -4, 2, 5, how could I get a 5th-degree polynomial? Am I missing something? (btw, I'm still reading all the answers and trying them out)

Comment: You need to know how many of each root there are, otherwise you can't know the exact makeup of the polynomial. Let's say you have a 5th degree polynomial, and you know that there's a double root at 4, a double root at 2, and a root at 5. You can pass in [4, 4, 2, 2, 5] to get the resultant polynomial. If you just know [4, 2, 5] and that it's a 5th degree, that's not enough information to make a polynomial. It can be [4, 4, 4, 2, 5], or [4, 2, 2, 5, 5] ... etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick for a polynomial to any degree. The asterisk symbol allows for any number of arguments.

```
def c_find(*roots):
    from sympy import Symbol
    x = Symbol('x')
    whole =1
    for root in roots:
        whole *=(x-root)
    print('f(x) =',whole.expand())
```

calling `c_find(3,4,5)` returns `f(x) = x**3 - 12*x**2 + 47*x - 60`

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but what if you have a fifth-degree polynomial but only with three roots?

Comment: If you want a polynomial to the 5th degree with only three roots add two zeros! For a polynomial to the nth degree with x number roots add (n-x) zeros to the roots passed to the function. Good question

Comment: In this way I think you add to a root of 0

Comment: yeah, whoops - you're right. You need to if you're roots are 3,4,5 you would need two add two more numbers to the argument passed to the function and those two numbers would need to come from the three roots you already know.

Comment: If I have to pass a list as an argument in your function. what should I add? I'm getting `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Symbol' and 'list'`.

Comment: Hmm, I don’t know why that is. As long as you’re defining the function exactly as shown above then it should be fine. To call the function all you   do is type c_find() filling the parenthesis with all of your roots separated by commas. I’m running python 3.7. This could be something specific to your build and I’d play around with it to see if you can find the error.

Comment: Sorry about that. I'm actually using a list of list and tried to loop over it correctly to pass it as the arg of the function. It gives me high-degree ploy since I loop it wrong. Haven't figure it out the right way.

Comment: Just posted my answer and finally got it. Thanks for your function.

Answer (score 2):

There's a basic `poly` set of functions in `numpy`:

```
In [44]: f = np.poly([-2,1,3])
In [45]: f
Out[45]: array([ 1., -2., -5.,  6.])
In [46]: np.roots(f)
Out[46]: array([-2.,  3.,  1.])
In [49]: np.polyval(f, np.arange(-3,5))
Out[49]: array([-24.,   0.,   8.,   6.,   0.,  -4.,   0.,  18.])
```

The values at a range of values can also be evaluated with:

```
In [53]: np.dot(np.arange(-3,5)[:,None]**np.array([3,2,1,0]), f)
Out[53]: array([-24.,   0.,   8.,   6.,   0.,  -4.,   0.,  18.])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `sympy` to build a polynomial from the roots and then get the coefficients:

```
from sympy import Symbol, poly

x = Symbol('x')

roots = [-1, 1]
expr = 1

# polynomial in format (x-a)(x-b)(x-c)...
for i in roots:
  expr *= (x - i)

p = poly(expr, x)
print(p)
print(p.all_coeffs())
```

Output:

```
Poly(x**2 - 1, x, domain='ZZ')
[1, 0, -1]
```

Note that this will work for an arbitrarily long list of roots.

For example if roots is `[-1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`

Output:

```
Poly(x**7 - 20*x**6 + 154*x**5 - 560*x**4 + 889*x**3 - 140*x**2 - 1044*x + 720, x, domain='ZZ')
[1, -20, 154, -560, 889, -140, -1044, 720]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def f(x): return (x - (-2)) * (x - 1) * (x - 2)
```

For the purpose of evaluating the polynomial at x, this should be as good as having the factors multiplied out symbolically.  To make multiple polynomial functions defined by roots, use a function factory.

```
def poly3(r1, r2, r3):
    def _poly3(x):
        return (x - r1) * (x - r2) * (x - r3)
    return _poly3

f2 = poly3(-2, 1, 2)

for i in range(-10, 11):
    assert f(i) == f2(i)
# no AssertionError means all tests pass
```

The following generalizes to n roots.

```
def polyn(*roots):
    def _polyn(x):
        val = 1
        for r in roots:
            val *= x - r
        return val
    return _polyn

f3 = polyn(-2, 1, 2)

for i in range(-10, 11):
    assert f(i) == f3(i)
# Above code passed on Win 10, 3.7.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. After playing around with your solutions. For my **Update** with repeated roots, I came up with the following solution:

```py
def find_all_polys(degree, roots):
    '''find all formats of polynomials with given degree and roots

    Args:
        degree (int): the degree of the polynomial
        roots (list): the list contains all given roots

    Returns:
        All simplified formats of polynomials with a given degree

    Notes:
        1. The degree of a polynomial determines its maximum number of
           all possible real roots.
        2. Each combination of roots for a given degree polynomial
           determines a simplified format of the polynomial (i.e., the
           coefficient of the highest-degree term is 1)
        3. The number of all possible formats for a n-th degree
           polynomial with m roots is defined as:
                            H(m, n-m)=C(m, n-m+m-1)
           Since the given roots will always be contained in the roots
           combination, the number of format variations depends on the
           combination of duplicated roots, which can be considered as
           a combination with repetition problem as defined above.

    '''

    from math import factorial
    from sympy import Symbol

    # counting number of all possible roots combinations
    nHr = lambda n,r: factorial(n+r-1)/(factorial(r)*factorial(n-1))
    n_all_roots = nHr(len(roots), degree-len(roots))

    # getting all roots combinations
    if len(np.unique(roots)) == len(roots):
        n_dups = degree-len(roots)
        roots_all_dups = []
        while True:
            # randomly select from the given roots
            roots_dups = np.random.choice(roots, n_dups).tolist()
            roots_dups.sort()

            # testing if the combination already exists
            if roots_dups not in roots_all_dups:
               roots_all_dups.append(roots_dups)
            else:
                if len(roots_all_dups) == n_all_roots:
                    break

        # adding duplicated roots to all given roots list
        for dups in roots_all_dups:
            dups.extend(roots)
        all_roots_combs = roots_all_dups

        # finding all possible formats of polynomials
        for counter, roots_combs in enumerate(all_roots_combs):
            x = Symbol('x'); term = 1
            for root in all_roots_combs[counter]:
                term *= (x-root)
            print(f'f(x) = {term.expand()}')

    else:
        raise ValueError('The root list should not contain duplicated roots')
```

For example:

```py
roots = [-2, 1, 3]
find_all_polys(degree=6, roots=roots)
```

will return:

```
f(x) = x**6 - 4*x**5 - 6*x**4 + 32*x**3 + x**2 - 60*x + 36
f(x) = x**6 - 6*x**5 + 50*x**3 - 45*x**2 - 108*x + 108
f(x) = x**6 - 9*x**5 + 24*x**4 + 2*x**3 - 99*x**2 + 135*x - 54
f(x) = x**6 - x**5 - 15*x**4 + 5*x**3 + 70*x**2 + 12*x - 72
f(x) = x**6 + 4*x**5 - 5*x**4 - 40*x**3 - 40*x**2 + 32*x + 48
f(x) = x**6 + x**5 - 11*x**4 - 13*x**3 + 26*x**2 + 20*x - 24
f(x) = x**6 - 2*x**5 - 8*x**4 + 14*x**3 + 11*x**2 - 28*x + 12
f(x) = x**6 - 11*x**5 + 40*x**4 - 30*x**3 - 135*x**2 + 297*x - 162
f(x) = x**6 - 5*x**5 + 4*x**4 + 14*x**3 - 31*x**2 + 23*x - 6
f(x) = x**6 - 7*x**5 + 12*x**4 + 14*x**3 - 59*x**2 + 57*x - 18
```